# What is wrong with this Apache httpd.conf file for vhosts?

Tags: apache, redirects, virtualhost, httpd.conf

**What is wrong here?**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.apples.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/apples.co.uk
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.apples\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.apples.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.bananas.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/bananas.co.uk
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.bananas\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bananas.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

**Problems:**

- `apples.co.uk` does correctly redirect to `www.apples.co.uk`, but
  `bananas.co.uk` redirects to `www.apples.co.uk`.
- When either `apples.co.uk`or `bananas.co.uk` redirects, the address
  bar results with `http://www.apples.co.uk//`.  What is causing that
  extra slash at the end?

Here the output of `apachectl -S` :

```
[Sun Jul 31 08:41:52 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.apples.co.uk (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:3)
         port 80 namevhost www.apples.co.uk (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:3)
         port 80 namevhost www.bananas.co.uk (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:11)
         port 80 namevhost servername.apples.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

I guess the first problem is caused by the `default server` setting.  How do I remove that?  Does there need to be a default?

I know I also need to add to `sites-enabled` to get rid of the warning, but I'll leave that for another question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FIRST:**

1. First defined VirtualHost will be used as catch all for unknown domain names.
2. Apache does not know about `apples.co.uk` -- it only knows about `www.apples.co.uk`. So it uses first Virtual Host to serve `apples.co.uk`. Redirect will work OK here.
3. Apache does not know about `bananas.co.uk` -- it only knows about `www.bananas.co.uk`. So it uses first Virtual Host to serve `bananas.co.uk` .. which is `www.apples.co.uk`. Therefore it will be redirected to `www.apples.co.uk`.

**To solve the above issue:** Add `ServerAlias apples.co.uk` line inside first virtual host and `ServerAlias bananas.co.uk` into second one. If you want to catch ANY subdomain as well -- add this line as well: `ServerAlias *.apples.co.uk` (the same for `bananas.co.uk`).

---

**SECOND:**

The `RewriteRule` URL will include leading slash if declared in server config / virtual host context. If this rewrite rule would be declared in .htaccess it would work fine, but here (inside VirtualHost declaration) you **need to remove slash after domain name** in `RewriteRule` target. That is why you are having double slash after domain name on redirect.

You can also speed up host matching a bit by replacing relatively expensive regex by simple string comparison: `!^www\.bananas\.co\.uk$` => `!=www.bananas.co.uk`.

---

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.apples.co.uk
   ServerAlias apples.co.uk
   DocumentRoot /var/www/apples.co.uk
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.apples.co.uk [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.apples.co.uk$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.bananas.co.uk
   ServerAlias bananas.co.uk
   ServerAlias *.bananas.co.uk
   DocumentRoot /var/www/bananas.co.uk
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.bananas.co.uk [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bananas.co.uk$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

---

> I guess the first problem is caused by the default server setting. How
>   do I remove that? Does there need to be a default?

Create VirtualHost for some fake domain name .. and place it first (before any other `<VirtualHost>` declarations) -- then you will see Apache's error page when such unknown domain name will be requested.